# Gamma function's mean and standard deviation through shape and rate

Tags: gamma-function, standard-deviation

I'm currently learning how to program neural networks.
In the most basic ones, you initialize your matrix with random numbers that are distributed using Gamma function.

I'm using a math library, that lets me initialize a Gamma function by giving values for `shape` and `rate`.

The most basic way to initialize it for the neural networks is to do it with a Gamma function with `mean 0` and `standard deviation 1`.
I'm struggling on how to connect these properties though.

What I have already learned, is that I can obtain my desired mean value with shape and rate like this:

$μ = k/β$

where k is the shape and β is the rate.

So far, i couldn't find / understand how to get a desired standard deviation though.

Extra: If you could explain using 1yr college math (if possible), that would be amazing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A gamma distribution has a **strictly positive** mean.  If $X$ is gamma distributed with shape $a$ and rate $b$, then the mean of $X$ is $$\mu = \operatorname{E}[X] = a/b,$$ and the standard deviation is $$\sigma = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[X]} = \sqrt{a}/b.$$  Note that $a$ and $b$ must be positive.

It follows from the above that, given a desired mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the shape and rate that produce a gamma distribution with that desired $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are:  $$a = (\mu/\sigma)^2, \quad b = \mu/\sigma^2.$$

For example:  If the desired mean is $\mu = 5$ and the desired standard deviation is $\sigma = 2$, then the shape would be $a = (5/2)^2 = 25/4$, and the rate would be $b = 5/2^2 = 5/4$.

Comment: Ok i see, thank you very much. One more question though: The fact that The distribution had a mean 0 was mentioned across few articles. Do you know what could that mean(pun not intended)? Since you stated it has to be a positive value, since well, we cannot divide by 0.