# estimate Gamma parameters based on mean and variance

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution

I am following these two approaches (which are the same)[this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280459/estimating-gamma-distribution-parameters-using-sample-mean-and-std) and  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810257/gamma-functions-mean-and-standard-deviation-through-shape-and-rate), to estimate the two parameters of Gamma dist based on mean and var. I am not sure why I cannot get the same mean and var from rgamma based on the estimated parameters in R:

```
 mean1=20
 var1=30

 shapeg = (mean1*2)/var1
 scaleg = var1/mean1

 nn=(rgamma(1000, shape = shapeg, scale = scaleg))
 mean(nn);
 var(nn);

 > mean(nn);
 [1] 1.975715
 > var(nn);
 [1] 3.6593
```

Based on https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html

The Gamma distribution with parameters shape = a and scale = s

The mean and variance are E(X) = a*s and Var(X) = a*s^2.

Based on this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280459/estimating-gamma-distribution-parameters-using-sample-mean-and-std

$\mbox{Var}[X] = \alpha \theta^2$

therefore, $\theta$ must be equal to scale in  R. SO I am replacing the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake is in your code. It looks like you tried to square with `*2` instead of `^2`. Maybe you were thinking of Python, which would use `**2`.

Comment: Yes, confused, thx a lot, worked, need 9 min to accept this as answer